# Comparing XAMPP and php -S localhost:8000, they look very different

Tags: php, testing, web, xampp

I've set up local testing using both XAMPP and php -S localhost:8000. When I compare the website that is produced from both, the website behaves and looks different from each other. However, the same codebase hosted on the web server looks completely fine and behaves alright.

How am I supposed to know if my changes will work properly on the actual web server if they don't show up properly during local testing?

I'm forced to test locally because my co-workers don't seem to know how to set up the dev environment for me to edit the files on a staging server accurately.... Please help!

Comment: you wont know before testing.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the xampp creates an extra path for each application and the php -S doesn't

Example:
You have your application under the

`C:/xampp/htdocs/myApp`

Your app would be served on

`localhost:<xamppPort>/myApp`

But if you're serving with php -S this extra `/myApp` path wouldn't exist

**How to make xampp works like php -S?**

You must change the xampp root directory to your project folder

1. Go to C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
2. Open httpd.conf
3. Find the DocumentRoot tag and change it from `DocumentRoot
   "C:/xampp/htdocs"` to `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myApp"`
4. Now find this Directory tag and change it to `<Directory
   "C:/xampp/htdocs/myApp">`
5. Restart Your Apache
6. Comment below if it worked